# Divide one 240 circuit into two 120s

Tags: wiring

Can I divide a 240 circuit into two 120s using two single pole breakers and the existing four wires with the single white common for both?

Comment: Look up MWBC(multi wire branch circuits).  You want both single breakers to have a handle tie, or use a double breaker.  For receptacles/lights you are limited to 15 or 20 amp breakers.

Comment: Got it  Thank you

Comment: How many amps is the existing circuit rated for?